# Similar solution as ClientIDMode="Static" on my HTML elements using runat="server" in ASP 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please I need help.
My app is in 3.5 version. I can't move to higher version.
All my css style are depends on #ids so solution can move ids to classes but it will be hard work.

On my html element when I put runat="server" attribute my ID's are dynamic. I need some solution similar in v4 where I can set ClientIDMode="Static".

Example

```
<ul id="myMenu" runat="server">
   <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Result with runat="server" is something like:

```
<ul id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_myMenu">
```

I know that in v4++ I can use ClientIDMode="Static" but I can't change my solution for reason from 3.5.

I can't find whole day any solution. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Sorry; there is no solution for you.  You need to change your CSS (use classes) or runtime version.

Comment: OOOOH NOOO thank you anyway.

Comment: Nope there is not any solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can modify your CSS to match *the end* of ID.

Instead of

```
#myMenu {

}
```

You can do

```
[id$="myMenu"] {

}
```

This will match element with ID *ending* in "myMenu" in your case

```
<ul id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_myMenu">
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B5S3r/2/

Comment: Glad it was helpful, please mark the solution as answer if it was useful.